# MacOS - Deleting old .IPA and .APK from Xamarin Folders

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There are two folders in my Xamarin Development Environment that I'd like to clean up:

APK Archive:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Archives/*
```

IPA Archive:

```
~/Library/Developer/XCode/Archives/*
```

Can I just go ahead and delete the contents of the folders? I do not need these files, I just want to make sure that nothing will be broken or something in my Xamarin Environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can delete them if you're sure that you no longer need them.

Here is a [guide](https://montemagno.com/cleanup-up-space-xamarin-dev-machine/) to other ways to reclaim space in a Xamarin dev environment.

Comment: +1 for the guide, Xamarin generates so many temp files, logs, etc. it's unreal, so this is nice to have.